# Updating separate MSSQL records in a loop, based on a shared ID

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a form with several fields set up as arrays, thus:

```
<input type="text" name="proj[]" id="proj[]" value="<?php echo $proj[0]; >?" />
<input type="text" name="budget[]" id="budget[]" value="<?php echo $budget[0]; >?" />
```

(For brevity, certain code features, like htmlspecialchars, have been redacted.)

There are four such groupings, and, upon INSERT, four separate records are created.

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {
$new = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO table (proj, budget, formId) 
VALUES(:proj, :budget, :formid)");
$data = array('proj'=>$_POST['proj'][$i],
'budget'=>$_POST['budget'][$i],'formid'=>$formId);
//formId comes from a calculation performed elsewhere (x=x+1)
$new->execute($data);
} ?>
```

The insert works fine, and I can call up the records and display them on my form after querying the database.

```
<?php while($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
$proj[] =   $row['proj'];
$budget[] = $row['budget'];
} ?>
```

When it comes to UPDATING them, however, I'm running into trouble. I can't figure out how to update the individual rows. This is what I've tried so far:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {
$upd = $con->prepare("UPDATE table SET proj=:proj, budget=:budget
WHERE formId = :formid");
$data = array('proj'=>$_POST['proj'][$i], 'budget'=>$_POST['budget'][$i],
'formid'=>$_SESSION['formId']);
$upd->execute($data);
}
```

And that's where I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to tell MSSQL that I'm updating separate rows that all have the same formId. The above code just sets everything to NULL. I've also tried $_SESSION['formId'][$i] (giving the session variable an index), and that just duplicates the first row three more times. The existing data gets overwritten with whatever's in proj[1] and budget[1].

So if the user takes proj[1]=100 and changes it to proj[1]= 50,
and if he takes proj[2]=50 and changes it to proj[2]=100, I need that to be reflected in the respective DB records. Everything that doesn't change needs to stay the same. Thoughts? I feel like I'm close, but missing something obvious.

Comment: They all have the same formid, but there has to be SOMETHING unique you can add to your WHERE statement to make the update unique.

Comment: @DigitalChris: Each row has an auto-incrementing UID. I'm trying to work out how to incorprate that UID into my UPDATE statement along with the formId. Any ideas?

Comment: Get that UID and add it to the WHERE like `AND UID=:UID`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I added the following SELECT and while() statements to the top of my for() loop:

```
//UID uniquely identifies each row
$getId = $con->prepare("SELECT UID FROM table WHERE formId = :formid");
$input = array('formid'=>$_SESSION['formId']);
$getId->execute($input);

//Assign the values of $row['UID'] to an array
while($row = $getId->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
$uid[] = $row['UID'];
```

And I modified my UPDATE statement to take the value of $uid[] in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE formId = :formid AND UID = :uid;
$data = array('formid'=>$_SESSION['formId'], 'uid'=>$uid[$i]);
```

Now each row updates independently of the others, as long as UID is unique and paired with its corresponding formId.